# Can Python Functions be used in Flask or Django?

Tags: python

I need help with a question I have in mind.I've been working on big data and machine learning lately.I'm going to do some work on twitter data first, but I don't want my work to remain only on the terminal screen.I want to see the data on the web, is it possible using flask or django?It doesn't have to be just twitter data, as I said at first, it could be any data.

For Example: I want to build a structure like this

[image]

```
from twython import Twython


    CONSUMER_KEY = '***'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = '***'
    ACCESS_TOKEN = '***'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '***'

    twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                      ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)




    user = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen='jack')

    print(user[0]['user']['friends_count'])
    print(user[0]['user']['statuses_count'])
    print(user[0]['user']['favourites_count'])
```

How do I use this code structure in django or flask? If I write this in a class, if I call it in django or flask, do I do a proper job?

Comment: In general Python functions can be used in Flask and Django, but that does not mean that your function operates in a ways that is suitable for WSGI applications. You will have to give details about your function to get detailed help.

Comment: Short answer is yes. Long answer is you need to be muuuuch more specific.

Comment: Yes, but you will usually want to store your result somewhere (e.g. in a database or in files) and show those on the Web, not compute your results on the fly when a request comes in.

Comment: guys, ı updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Short answer yes, all kind of python function will work.

`Flask` and `Django` will help you to create either `API or web interface`. For this, you need a `web server`.  Here are things that you need to look while using your any function in these frameworks.

- Install a web server
- Install `Django` or `Flask`
- Integrate Web server with installed application
- Define Entry point for your request. ex `www.abc.com/landing_page` for this you need to create a host on your system `www.abc.com` when this points to your application then define a route `landing_page` so it will handle the incoming request.
- Then check how `Django` and `Flask` handle these request and define request handler
- After handling these request finally call your function in the request handler
- Final if API return response in `JSON, TEXT` or any other format else showing web page then call desired template and display page.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Is there a document about this?

Comment: @LisaAnabel Which one you are looking for `Django` or `Flask`. There  are number of resources for it. Will tell you accordingly.

Comment: "It doesn't matter, I just want my transactions to be fast."

"I will also run big data and machine learning algorithms at the back. (Numpy, matploit, knn algorithm etc)

Comment: I still waiting for a resources

Comment: @LisaAnabel yes it will have more than 1 link, Here is link to start installing or working on flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/, or you can connect me at rakeshkaswan8356@gmail.com. I will help you in steps.